# How to bind external json data with sap.m table controls using xml view in UI5?

Tags: json, data-binding, sapui5, hana-xs

`I am trying to bind JSON data from an external file to my UI5 table.
following is my component.js code -

```
var oModel = new JSONModel("/businessData.json");
     this.setModel(oModel);
```

The json file is in the same folder as component.js

Following is my view code-

```
<Table id="idProductsTable" items="{       
            path:'/businessData'
        }">
            <headerToolbar>
                <Toolbar>
                    <Label text="Products"></Label>
                </Toolbar>
            </headerToolbar>
            <columns>
                <Column>
                    <Label text="Product" />
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Label text="Supplier" />
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Label text="Dimensions" />
                </Column>
            </columns>
            <items>
                <ColumnListItem>
                    <cells>
                        <ObjectIdentifier title="{COUNTRY}" text="{COUNTRY}" />
                    </cells>
                    <Text text="{REGION}"></Text>
                    <Text text="{CITY}"></Text>
                </ColumnListItem>
            </items>
        </Table>
```

I am getting no data in table...Please help

Comment: Can you share JSON data and a screenshot of your folder structure?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have specified the path for `items` aggregation correctly, the only thing missing in your code is `.` in the path for JSON file.

```
var oModel = new JSONModel("./businessData.json");
```

Answer (score 0):

declare your model like below

var omodel = new sap.ui.model.json.jsonmodel()